# Accessing Task properties via reflection only works if the properties are explicitly accessed in my code

Tags: c#, reflection, task, ms-project

I'm trying to access a property of a `Task` in an MS Project via `System.Type.GetProperty("Finish")`, but it looks like the property (and others like it e.g. `Number1`) is not accessible via reflection unless my code specifically uses that property. Is this a compiler setting that I can change? I'm writing a synchronization engine so it is impossible to tell ahead of time what field of a `Task` the client system may request.

So with the example below info will be null.

```
System.Type ty = typeof(Task);
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo info = ty.GetProperty("Finish");
```

but with the code below info is returned as a valid PropertyInfo object.

```
Task tk = activeProject.ProjectSummaryTask;
object done = tk.Finish;
System.Type ty = typeof(Task);
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo info = ty.GetProperty("Finish");
```

I basically expected `GetProperty()` to work for all the properties listed in the API for `Task` (which are quite a few).

Here is a link to the API for the `Finish` property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.msproject.task.finish?view=office-project-server

Comment: What Task type is this? It's not System.Threading.Tasks.Task or Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task because neither one of those has a Finish property. I suspect you are accessing different types with the same simple name that are in different namespaces in these two cases.

Comment: This is the task: **using Task = Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Task;**

Answer (score 0):

Use the [GetField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.msproject.task.getfield?view=office-project-server) method of the [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.msproject.task?view=office-project-server) object to return the value for a variable field.

You'll need to identify the field by the internal field ID--use the intrinsic constant (e.g pjTaskFinish) or its numerical value (188743716).

Alternatively, you can convert friendly field names to constants using the [FieldNameToFieldConstant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.msproject._global.fieldnametofieldconstant?view=office-project-server#Microsoft_Office_Interop_MSProject__Global_FieldNameToFieldConstant_System_String_Microsoft_Office_Interop_MSProject_PjFieldType_) method of the Application object.

p.s. the VBA-version of the documentation contains more information; most, if not all, objects/methods/properties are the same.

Comment: Thanks very much, and I am aware of this method and have used it in the past, but the problem with it is that "GetField" will always return a String - not a value. This means that I cannot tell the type of the data unless I try parsing it in multiple different formats. GetField for the "PercentComplete" field, for example, will give something like "10%", while using Task.PercentComplete directly or via reflection (when it is reflected) gives a number. I need access to the raw data, not the formatted data as provided by GetField.